# Android :Bluetooth insecure connection with hf reader

Tags: android, bluetooth, insecure-connection

How to create a insecure connection between two devices and get the data.As of now I am using [Bluetooth chat app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/) in that I think it is possible to make insecure connection,but I was trying from last two days not getting any idea,can you please suggest me how can do the insecure connection between android and hf devices or please share if any source code is available.